# Zero ohm resistor tolerance?

Tags: resistors

This [0Ω resistor](http://uk.farnell.com/multicomp/mc0603wg00000t5e-tr/resistor-0603-0-063w-0r/dp/1692453?Ntt=MC%200.063W%200603%201%25%200R) has a tolerance of ±1%.

Well it would only be +1% at best because you can't have a negative resistance* but still 1% of zero is still zero?

Shouldn't it be something like 0\$\Omega\$ + 0.001R?

---

*except in very special cases with certain devices but never over the full operating range.

Comment: -1R, the answer to all our energy problems.

Comment: Next thing we know overunity.com will have a section on negative resistors.

Comment: They already do. http://jlnlabs.online.fr/cnr/index.htm  This, of course, originated from some idiot journalists framing an experiment as a "breakthrough in superconductors" because they don't understand electronics.  You can't put a current through one branch of a circuit and measure a voltage across another branch and call it resistance.

Comment: and it has a temperature coefficient!

Comment: @Thomas O: It might also be -1% because 0\$\Omega\$ * -0.01 is still 0\$\Omega\$ (not negative).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you look at a "proper" data sheet (example: http://www.yageo.com/documents/recent/PYu-RC0603_51_RoHS_L_4.pdf) you'll usually find that the zero ohm resistor is defined separately using something like < 0.05R.

In this case, you're looking at a more or less automatically generated set of data which is probably more relevant to the other resistors in the range.  Multicomp in this case refers to multiple sources so the parts could be coming from anywhere; the data in this case is fairly general and is most likely the lowest common denominator for a variety of alternative devices.

Comment: Even for this "multicomp" part the datasheet seems to call out the tolerance for the zero ohm resistor seperately. It seems it's just the website that has the nonsensical tolerance.

Answer (score 12):

Yeah, that doesn't make sense.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-ohm_link

> The resistance is only approximately zero; only a maximum (typically 10–50 mΩ) is specified. Thus, a fractional tolerance (as a percentage of the zero-ohm ideal value) would be infinite and is not specified.

Comment: A fractional tolerance wouldn't be infinite though, it would be zero, and finite, right?

Comment: if your in a situation where 10-50 mOhm matters, or comes even remotely close to mattering, don't use a 0 ohm resistor.  I mean a 1 inch 10mil trace on 1oz copper results in roughly 50 mOhm resistance.

Comment: @Thomas - not the first problem with the quality of the supplied information on Wikipedia. I'm not a fan.

Comment: @ThomasO: Why?  The percent error is divided by the accepted value, which in this case is 0.  Anything divided by 0 is infinite.

Comment: @stevenvh: You mean that you can't just blindly trust everything on it, and have to read critically, just like every other source of information in the universe?  I'm horrified!

Comment: @endolith - Terrible, isn't it? Whereas lemmas in regular encyclopedia are written by trustworthy specialists on Wikipedia anyone who feels like it can write an article. No special knowledge required. When checking lemmas I know something about I found at least 1 error on most of them. The self-correcting thing is just a dream, but doesn't work to the level that the information is of a high level. Oh yes, did you notice that the most occurring note is "citation needed"?

Comment: @stevenvh: You're complaining that Wikipedia requires all facts to be backed up by reliable sources?

Comment: @endolith - No, I'm complaining that those facts are often missing, in particular in those many cases where the "citation needed" appears, which is more or less a few times in every article

Answer (score 6):

Apparently someone got carried away and thought that just because it looks like a resistor, it should have a tolerance like one.

Well, it's really just a resistor shaped piece of wire, so the only thing that would make much sense would be to spec 'not more than X amount of resistance', where X would presumably be a few milli-ohms.

If it was absolutely necessary to state it as a tolerance, it wouldn't be incorrect to say X/2 +/- 50%, but who has ever heard of a 50% tolerance part?

Comment: You clearly have not had to purchase enough capacitors if you have not heard of 50% tolerance. Supercaps can be hilarious in their specs.

Comment: -20% to +80% is often seen for super caps.

Comment: i guess i should have been more specific, and said who's ever heard of a 50% *resistor*; caps are notoriously widely spec'd.