# 4/5 band resistor - extra black band

Tags: resistors, repair, tolerance, component-values

I have two resistors which need to be replaced. I tried to determine the value, but it can't make sense of these black bands:
[image: Resistors in question]
For reference the bands are:

- brown - silver - green - brown - black
- brown - silver - red - brown - black

Since a silver line can only be part of the multiplier, that means the black line on the right has to be the tolerance. Black can not be used for a tolerance from what I've read.

Is this black line a tolerance value or something else?

Comment: You are reading the color code in the wrong direction.  The two big resistors are to be read right to left.  The last (leftmost) band is a tolerance specifier.  Normally silver by itself means 10% and gold 5%.

Comment: Thanks Olin. So then these are 0.15 and 0.12 ohm 1% resistors?

Comment: @tehwalris Divide those numbers by 10 because of the leading zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think I've ever seen a resistor value with a leading zero (usually those super-low values are marked with the value in numerals), but that's what those appear to be. 0.012\$\Omega\$ 1% and 0.015\$\Omega\$ 1% are what I see (reading from right to left, as Olin suggests, but I think the silver is a multiplier and the brown is the tolerance).

Here's a 0.015\$\Omega\$ 1% resistor (courtesy Digikey):

[image]

Comment: I was initially using an app to determine the values and it wouldn't accept the leading black/zero. That's what got me confused.