# Hello, Im trying to identify this Resistor

Tags: components

This is from a surgical operating table. I believe this resistor is bad. Im not 100% sure. I test it and it gives me no reading at all, no resistance reading nor contuinity reading.

[image]

Edit* Added a picture of the underside.

[image]

Comment: Looks like some power resistor. The fact it is required to be raised is probably due to it is getting very hot. But I don't think the value can be determined from this image.

Comment: How can I find its value? I have no service manual, nor schematics.

Comment: @ItsMitch Find a good unit and test the part in it? There don't appear to be any markings on that part, so there's no way of telling what the correct value is.

Comment: This is the only unit in our lab right now.

Comment: Is there any markings on the bottom of it maybe? Can you tell what is it's function?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! This appears to be a repair question. Please be aware that questions on the reverse engineering, modification and/or repair of consumer electronics, appliances, or other devices must involve specific troubleshooting steps and demonstrate a good understanding of the underlying design of the device being repaired, so that you can ask specific, focused questions that can be answered concisely. More information can be found [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/2478/11683).

Comment: Added a picture of the underside. One leg is connected to power input, the other leg is connected to a relay

Comment: Can you tell what kind of relay is that (and which relay pin it is connected to) and what power input is there?

Comment: Single Pole Double Throw 12V

Comment: sorry its actually 26V

Comment: No way to tell by looking at it. If you could trace out the entire circuit (including the load on the relay) you might be able to reverse engineer it. As @DaveTweed says, you'll need to do a fair bit more homework to get the necessary info.

Comment: related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/296421/resistor-with-only-2-color-bands

Comment: @JohnLaRooy How did you even find that one? :)

Comment: Also this one: looks like the bands can fade away on those resistors :( https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/246322/4-5-band-5-resistor-with-superfluous-black-end

Comment: @EugeneSh. google image search

Comment: You can see the ghost of one of the faded bands in the second picture.

Answer (score 1):

To sum up:

1. It's a power resistor. If you measure the body size and length you could likely find out what wattage it was.
2. It has a color band, and likely had more before the heat burned them away.
3. You are unlikely to ever measure continuity through a resistor. It's the opposite of what a continuity test measures. The open circuit and no resistance tells you that it's damaged though.
4. Find out what it connects to and what voltage may be across it would go a long way into guesstimating the resistance and confirming the wattage.

Since you said 26V power input, and as a resistor on the coil for the relay, the real question is what is the model of the relay. This will tell you the intended coil voltage and amperage, which you can then use to figure out the resistor value. It's basically a voltage divider. Or if it's on the switched pins of the relay, trace it out.

The other options are to contact the manufacturer, Google search for pictures of the circuit board hopefully with the resistor color bands in view, or ask someone to take pictures or measure the resistor in a good model.

Comment: Yes I do believe its a voltage divider. The voltage inpit for the relay is 12v

Comment: What's the model number of the relay?

Comment: t9as5d22-12 Relay model

Comment: If the circuit is 26V to resistor to relay coil to ground, and the relay coil is 144 ohms and 12V, that's 83 mA. The resistor would be 14V / 0.083 = 16.8 ohms and 14V * 0.083 = 1.16 Watts, so  1.5 or 2 watt resistor would be used.

Comment: @Passerby: That should be 168 ohms. Since it's a voltage divider, the resistors should have the same ratio as the voltages so `R = 144 * 14 / 12`

Comment: Typo. Period got added. The math is right though.  14v / 0.083 A = 168 ohms.