# What does the tolerance mean for the 0 ohm resistor

Tags: resistors, tolerance

What actually is the percentage tolerance if resistor is 0 ohm?

Comment: Like any other resistor, the 0 Ohm resistor has a tolerance specified by the manufacturer. There is not a generic tolerance for this resistor, the only obvious difference with other resistors is that it can only be positive tolerance

Comment: Although it must be specified differently, as 1% vs 10% of zero is still zero.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Zero ohm resistor tolerance?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5369/zero-ohm-resistor-tolerance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In practice, it means the 0 R resistor belongs to a family of resistors from a manufacturer that all have that tolerance.

For example, a manufacturer will make a family of 1 % resistors. All the parts in this family have a tolerance of 1 %. The family includes a 0 R resistor so this is also specified as 1 %.

Mathematically, its nonsense. But it allows the 0 R resistor to be clearly recognised as a member of that family, rather than be set apart by slightly different specs. The manufacturers appear to prefer to have that consistency, reasonably enough.

Comment: Reputable manufacturers post data like < 50 mOhm and not nonsensical % of 0 ohm.

Comment: @Arsenal, in the datasheet specs they will but not in the family summary and marketing summary, the component's named value there is 0 R. It's harmless enough though, it doesn't mislead people into design errors.

Comment: The problem is that the distributors do not :). Thank you very much.

Comment: @PeterJ_01, yes the distributors will use the manufacturers' marketing summary. And you're welcome :-)